# Jellyfin alongside Nextcloud snap on one PC

Tags: networking, ssl

I have running Nextcloud snap instance with all SSL certs, domain and etc. but also I have Jellyfin running on the same PC and I want to access it via the domain not like now with the PC IP. My question is how to make the Jellyfin instance accessible via domain with SSL certs ?
I'm using Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what SSL certificate you have.

### If you have a wildcard, let's encrypt or self signed certificate:

You could setup a wildcard, or two 3rd level domains to point to your PC. Then you could run a reverse proxy in front of Nextcloud and Jellyfin to properly route the traffic. You can then:

- terminate the SSL on the proxy and have localhost traffic unencrypted
- terminate the SSL on the proxy and reencrypt it with a selfsigned
  certificate. You then also need to setup SSL on nextcloud and jellyfin themselves.
- pass the SSL connection through the proxy and terminate it on nextcloud/jellyfin

You'd access it with `https://nextcloud.example.tld` and `https://jellyfin.example.tld`

### If you have a single domain certificate:

Setup a reverse proxy to route path `/jellyfin` to the jellyfin and `/nextcloud` to the nextcloud. You then have to update their config so they expect different base url.

- Jellyfin docs: https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/networking/index.html#base-url
- Nextcloud docs: https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Putting-the-snap-behind-a-reverse-proxy

In this case you only have these SSL options:

- terminate the SSL on the proxy and have localhost traffic unencrypted
- terminate the SSL on the proxy and reencrypt it with a selfsigned
  certificate. You then also need to setup SSL on nextcloud and jellyfin themselves.

How to setup SSL termination on the proxy depends on what proxy will you be using, so I can't help you with that now.

You'd access it with `https://example.tld/nextcloud` and `https://example.tld/jellyfin`

## Another approach

Since you want to use a friendly URLs instead of IPs, it doesn't seem like this would interest you but it's an option nonetheless.

You could change the ports jellyfin and nextcloud listens to, use the same certificate for both and then access either one by specifying the port.

This would actually work by default, since Nextcloud listens on port 443 and Jellyfin on port 8920

You'd access it with `https://example.tld`(:443) and `https://example.tld:8920`